# Need Regular expressionless for the below scenarios

Tags: regex, jmeter

```
/druid-web/filesetup/previewFileMap/2c91808b4e8f22e8014eaaa9b5d61582
```

How can i identify the regular expression for the above ??

I Tried below scenarios :

```
previewFile=(.+?)& and {\\previewFile"\\":\\"(\w+)\\"
```

Comment: What do you want to match? All parts?

Comment: Maybe [`(?:/[^/]*)*/previewFileMap/(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lF4vX4/2)?

Comment: Only for this id 2c91808b4e8f22e8014eaaa9b5d61582 Maroun

Comment: expression is not working (?:/[^/]*)*/previewFileMap/(\S+)? getting error message java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 59: https://ip /druid-web/filesetup/previewFile/${previewFile}?druid_d_c_t=1658964A1F64EF6B438362835D50EE2D&p_auth=TlMLpXk4
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the id, try to use this:

```
.+?\/previewFileMap\/(\w+)$
```

[Live example](https://regex101.com/r/vV8vT5/1)

The above example assumes that the part `/druid-web/filesetup` is not significant. Otherwise, if it is, you should modify the regex to fit your requirements, i.e.

```
\/druid-web\/filesetup\/previewFileMap\/(\w+)$
```